# the image is smaller than its respective imageView with a deforming rotation

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-imageview, bitmapfactory

I have specified an area for the `imageView` in the layout, in which I should display an image by referring to its path. Now, I got the image displayed on its respective `imageview` but

(1) the image is smaller than the allotted are for the `imageView`. And I want the imgae
    to fit exactly the `imageView`

(2) the image is rotated 90 degrees anticlockwise. I want it to be 
    displayed normally without rotation?

Please help me to achieve the aforementioned points

***Last Update***

Java_Code:

```
private void displayMeetinPointImageInsideImageView(DataBaseRow dataBaseRow, ImageView imgSpaceIv) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (dataBaseRow == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "@displayMeetinPointImageInsideImageView(): The Object Of The DataBaseRow Class Is NULL, Maybe "
                + "It Was Not Instantiated.");
        return;
    } else if (imgSpaceIv == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "@displayMeetinPointImageInsideImageView(): The Variable Of Type ImageView Is NULL, Maybe It Was "
                + "Not Instantiated.");
        return;
    } else if (dataBaseRow.getImgPath().isEmpty()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "@displayMeetinPointImageInsideImageView(): dataBaseRow.getImgPath() Is Empty");
        return;
    } else {
        String imgPathString = dataBaseRow.getImgPath();

        Options options = new Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 3;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPathString);
        Bitmap imgbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPathString, options);
        imgSpaceIv.setImageBitmap(imgbitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: error message shows that the bitmap you want to load is to large so its giving you out of memory error. before setting bitmap decode and set decoded bitmap to image view.

Comment: your are correct, though after decoding the image, i received defected output. i will post the update shortly

Answer (score 0):

Look at your logs:

```
dataBaseRow.getImgPath()= /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/MPL/5th guy hinging.jpeg
```

There is space in your filename.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to help me. regarding your notice, yes I give the user a space to set any name for the picture taken and the user can specify a name of the image with some spaces, is it wrong?!

Comment: @Elpharaoh Yes it is wrong. You can't have spaces in a filename. Try to replace your spaces by underscores, it will fix your problem I think.

Comment: But you have edit all your question so my comment is out of subject now, and my answer too.

Comment: I am sorry if that was should not be done that way. but unfortunately, your answer was not a solution to my question. Also, i would like to tell you, I thought it should be done that way, which is only to keep the last updated state of the problem